# Unable to execute the same script in Leetcode but works fine with VSCode TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

The below code to check if a string is a palindrome runs fine in VSCode:

```
def isPalindrome(s):
    rev = ""
    #print(s)
    for i in s:
        rev = i+ rev
    #print(rev)
    if (rev == s):
        return True
    else:
        return False
print(isPalindrome("-121"))
```

However, when running with the Leetcode compiler, I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable 
    for i in s:
Line 4 in isPalindrome (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().isPalindrome(param_1)
Line 32 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 42 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

Can anyone point out what am I missing here? I don't think the code is incorrect here.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, Leetcode gives you real number type. You needs to add `s = str(s)` to ensure the input is a string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to use a list explicitly instead of the string. Here is an example:

```py
def isPalindrome(s):
    return s == s[::-1]

print(isPalindrome(list("-121")))
```